# Reset an attribute to default value

Tags: perl, attributes, moose

I can declare an attribut with Moose like this:

```
has 'attr' => (is => 'rw', isa => 'Int', default => 10);
```

Is it possible to reset this value to the default value?

Example:

```
$obj->attr(5); # sets attr to 5
$obj->_reset_attr;
print $obj->attr; # will print 10
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you do this:

```
has 'attr' => (
  is => 'rw',
  isa => 'Int',
  lazy => 1,
  default => 10,
  clearer => '_clear_attr',
);
```

then you can do:

```
my $obj = Class->new;
print $obj->attr; # 10
$obj->attr(5);
print $obj->attr; # 5
$obj->_clear_attr;
print $obj->attr; # 10
```

The combination of `lazy` and `clearer` is important here.

Comment: Wow. And I used to think that `default` and `lazy` could not be combined. Is this a recent improvement to `Moose`?

Comment: @innaM nope, it's worked as far back as I can recall. It's more common to use `lazy` with `builder` (on the assumption that the builder does something expensive, or dependent on other data), but `default` is like a very simple builder :)

Comment: Btw, clearer also appears to work if 'attr' is=>'ro.  This is useful if you're lazy-loading a value from a database, and you know said value from said database has changed.  Just attr->_clear_attr, and next time 'attr' is accessed, Moose will re-lazy-load the refreshed value from the database.